# in CakePHP I want to have 2 cookies as they need different expiry times...can I do this?

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I have been trying like this -

```
 // ================
// = set a Cookie for the users city =
// ================
function set($cityId = null){

    $this->components[] = 'RequestHandler';

    $this->components[] = 'Cookie';
    $this->Cookie->name = 'Exampleoffers';  
    //$this->Cookie->time =  3600;  // or '1 hour' 
    //$this->Cookie->path = '/bakers/preferences/';   
    $this->Cookie->domain = 'www.example.co.uk';     
    $this->Cookie->secure = false;  
    $this->Cookie->key = 'kkjdDqSI232qs*&sXOw!';

    $cities = ($this->City->find('list'));  

    if($cities[$cityId]) {
        $this->Cookie->write ("Deal.city_id", (int) $cityId, false, "+2 months");

    } else {
        $this->Cookie->write ("Deal.city_id", key($cities), false, "+2 months");

    }
```

however, I am not sure if it is clashing with my Authsome cookie (?) or something else, but I am unable to read this value back.

Is there some way to specify which cookie you want to read() from in CakePHP?

Is there a way to have a cookie with 2 diffferent values of expiry times? - i.e. a cookie has User.id with a expiry of 1 week, and a Deal.city_id with a expiry of 2 months, say? Or am I right to think I DO need 2 cookies?

many thanks for any tips. It's cake 1.3 btw !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, remember cookies are saved on the system so if you only save the cookie one time on that system it will have the set values, however, you cannot have 2 cookies with the same name set, which means that when you go and save the cookies you'll have to do this:

```
$this->Cookie->write('Name1', $data, false, $time);

$this->Cookie->write('Name2', $data, false, $time);
```

If you don't, one will overwrite the other.

EDIT: Adding some links in case you have more doubts:

API page of CookieComponent: http://api13.cakephp.org/class/cookie-component

Cookbook page of CookieComponent: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1280/Cookies

Comment: hi this will save it to the same cookie though, as 'name1' and 'name2' are just the array keys in the one cookie, no?

Comment: They will be saved to the sites cookie yes, but they will be different cookies, you can access each one by doing this:

$this->Cookie->read('Name1') or 'Name2'

Comment: I added some links to my answer in case you want to dig a little further